# Python: Elements of dictionary

Tags: python

```
def big(dict, n):
    line = []

    for k in dict:
       if k > n:
            line.append(k)
            return line
```

I have to find all the elements in dict larger than n.

However, my code only returns the largest number in dict larger than n.

What do I need to do in order to make it correct?

Comment: what you are trying to check python dict has key and value you are trying to compare with key or value ?

Comment: what does your dict look like? `for k in dict` loops over the *keys*. (Also, don't use "dict" as a name, as it shadows the `builtin` `dict`.

Comment: my dictionary looks something like {'a':10,'b':15, 'c':12}

Comment: Right, so you want to iterate over the *values*: use `for k in dict.itervalues()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `return line` is tabbed too far over, so it returns when the *first* **key** larger than `n` is found *(Note: a dictionary isn't ordered by the way you write it)*, rather than going over all keys before returning. Try:

```
def big(dic, n):
    line = []
    for k in dic:
        if k > n:
            line.append(k)
    return line
```

In fact, you might prefer it to use list comprehension (and the function becomes just one line).

```
def big(dic, n):
    return [k for k in dic if k>n]
```

.

Dictionaries compomise of key value pairs, `{key: value}` and when we iterate over a dictionary we are iterating over it's keys.  This explains the use of the variable `k` to iterate over the **keys**. That is,

```
[k for k in dic] = [key1, key2, ...]
```

Hence, if you want to find that with the largest **value** in the dictionary, you can use:

```
    return [dic[k] for k in dic if dic[k]>n]
```

*Note: I've changed the variable name to `dic` since (as @AndrewJaffe mentions) `dict` is a built-in object, and renaming it here may cause unexpected things to occur, and is generally considered bad practise. For example, if you wanted to check `type(dic)==dict`*.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe Whoops! Corrected.

Comment: I tried your codes and they return everything in dictionary :(

Comment: @Kevv Could stem from the fact that `string > n` (for every string and every integer). Are the **keys** to your dictionary strings? if so is it the largest **value** you want to find (and if so, see last line in my answer :) )?

If not, please could you include the offending dictionary in your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
def big(dic, n):
    line = []
    for k in dic:
       if  dic[k]> n:      #compare value instead of key      
            line.append(k) #use k if you're appending key else dic[k] for val
            return line
```

**output**:

```
>>> print big({'a':10,'b':15, 'c':12},11)
['c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Naively iterating over a dictionary gives you a sequence of *keys*. not *values*.

So to do what you want, you need [itervalues](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues):

```
for k in d.itervalues():    ### call it "d" rather than "dict"
   if k>n:
      line.append(k)
```

Or, as others have pointed out, use a list comprehension.

Also, don't use `dict` for the name, as it shadows a builtin.

Answer (score 0):

move the return statement backwards two tabs otherwise it will return on the first value larger than n.